# cant move slicknav from top of page

Tags: responsive-design, positioning, slicknav

Is there a way to have content above slicknav menu when responsive? Im trying to move it from being at the top of the page, im trying to get:

====CONTACT DETAILS====

====LOGO====

====SLICKNAV====

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you have already tried - but you would normally use the prependTo property to place where the menu goes.

e.g.

```
<div id="d1">Before</div>
<div id="d2">some other content</div>
<div id="d3">third row of content</div>
<div>
    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="d4">4th row of content</div>
```

and script

```
$('ul').slicknav({
        prependTo:'#d3'
});
```

Please see this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vzhc83u6/) for an example of the above